# make htaccess opencart mod_rewrite work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart, opencart-module

I am trying to rewrite

http://valencia/vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris
to
http://valencia/vazi/?brand=cristal-de-paris

this is my rule:
`RewriteRule (.*)/brand-(.*)/? /$1/?brand=$2 [L,QSA]`

but i get redirect to http://valencia/vazi/?brand=cristal-de-paris
because of opencart rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So redirect is the problem ... I need just working url
http://valencia/vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris
without redirecting

rewrite.log:
https://www.valencia.com.ua/rewrite.log

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I modified the rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/(brand-)*(.*)/? index.php?_route_=$1/&brand=$3 [L,QSA]
```

But I also get redirect ...

Rewrtite log:

```
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.316081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] add path info postfix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi -> C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.316081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris -> vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.316081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] applying pattern '(.*)/(brand-)*(.*)/?' to uri 'vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris'
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] rewrite 'vazi/brand-cristal-de-paris' -> 'index.php?_route_=vazi/&brand=cristal-de-paris'
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] split uri=index.php?_route_=vazi/&brand=cristal-de-paris -> uri=index.php, args=_route_=vazi/&brand=cristal-de-paris
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] trying to replace prefix C:/Z-WWW/valencia/ with /
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] strip matching prefix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php -> index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e3ff50/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e509a0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php -> index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e509a0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] applying pattern '(.*)/(brand-)*(.*)/?' to uri 'index.php'
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.317081 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e509a0/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] pass through C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] add path info postfix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi -> C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi/
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi/ -> vazi/
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] applying pattern '(.*)/(brand-)*(.*)/?' to uri 'vazi/'
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Z-WWW/valencia/vazi' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] rewrite 'vazi/' -> 'index.php?_route_=vazi/&brand='
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] split uri=index.php?_route_=vazi/&brand= -> uri=index.php, args=_route_=vazi/&brand=&brand=cristal-de-paris
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] trying to replace prefix C:/Z-WWW/valencia/ with /
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] strip matching prefix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php -> index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e4dfc0/initial] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e40788/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php -> index.php
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e40788/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] applying pattern '(.*)/(brand-)*(.*)/?' to uri 'index.php'
[Mon Mar 13 12:55:20.419087 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2524:tid 868] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:62147] 127.0.0.1 - - [valencia/sid#ce1ad8][rid#1e40788/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Z-WWW/valencia/] pass through C:/Z-WWW/valencia/index.php
```

Please help ...

Comment: I'd get rid of your new RewriteRule in .htaccess. Opencart  - go into your admin > Catalog > Manufacturers and set an SEO URL for your brand there (i.e. brand-baccarat). 

OR am I missing something?

Comment: I have made custom manufacture filter in every category. I use seo url from manufactures in links – baccarat is value of seo url. But it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in opencart SeoPro module which made redirect ...